# Avoid the fluxbox slit taskbar side panel auto hide

Tags: desktop-environment, display-settings, settings, panel, fluxbox

This is my question: how to configure the Fluxbox  slit side panel (taskbar which contains dockable apps) for avoiding to auto-hide?

Comment: Better if you answer your own question rather than editing the question to include your solution. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED BY MYSELF Edited **`~/.fluxbox/init`** and replaced `session.screen0.slit.autoHide:  true` with `session ... autoHide: false`